# Show the following is Local Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

$X_t$ bessel square process which satisfies $$\mathop{dx_t}= 2(a+1) \mathop{dt} +2 \sqrt{x_t} \mathop{dB_t}$$ and $u$ is a function which satisfies $x^2 u'' +x u' -u(a^2 + b x^{2p+2})= 0$.
How can I show the function:

$$u\left(\sqrt {X_t}\right) ( X_t)^{-a/2} \exp\left(-b/2 \cdot\int_0^tX_s^p \mathop{ds}\right)$$ is a local martingale.

I tried with ito formula but finding derivatives of product of three terms comes with many unmanagable terms. Any suggestions!

Comment: @ Raj your last resort is Itô the trick is not to care too much about the dB terms and to focus on the "dt" which shall be null thank's too your pde. Regards

Comment: Thank you so much. So I have to correct the equation u satisfies.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether the comment above is supposed to be addressed at saz for editing the post, TheBridge for the comment, or saz for the answer below. But in any case it is not an answer, so I converted it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's introduce some notation first:

$$\begin{align*} Y_t &:= \int_0^t X_s^p \, ds \\
Z_t &:= \underbrace{u(\sqrt{X_t}) \cdot X_t^{-a/2}}_{=:f(X_t)} \cdot \underbrace{\exp \left(- \frac{b}{2} Y_t \right)}_{=:g(Y_t)} \end{align*} $$

By the definition of $X_t$, we have $\langle X,Y \rangle_t=0$ which means that the mixed derivatives in the Itô formula will vanish. Moreover, $\langle Y \rangle_t =0$. Hence,

$$\begin{align*} Z_t - Z_0 &= \int_0^t f'(X_s) \cdot g(Y_s) \, dX_s + \int_0^t f(X_s) \cdot g'(Y_s) \, dY_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(X_s) \cdot g(Y_s) \, d\langle X \rangle_s \\ &=: I_1+I_2+I_3 \end{align*}$$

We write

$$I_j = \int_0^t \varphi_j(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t \psi_j(s) \, ds, \qquad j=1,2,3.$$

Since we want to prove that $(Z_t)_t$ is a local martingale, it suffices to show $$\psi_1(t)+\psi_2(t)+\psi_3(t)=0$$ for any $t \geq 0$. Using that $\langle X \rangle_t = 4X_t \, dt$ we find by some straight-forward calculations

$$\begin{align*}\psi_1(t) &= f'(X_t) g(Y_t) 2(a+1) \\ &= \left(u'(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-1/2} -a \, u(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-1} \right) (a+1) \cdot g(Y_t) \\
\psi_2(t) &= f(X_t) g'(Y_t) \, X_t^p \\ &= - \frac{b}{2} f(X_t) g(Y_t) X_t^p \\
\psi_3(t) &= \frac{1}{2} f''(X_t) g(Y_t) 4X_t \\ &=  \bigg( \frac{1}{2} u''(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-1} + \left(- \frac{a}{2}-1 \right) u'(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-3/2} \\ &\quad - \frac{a}{2} u'(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-3/2} - a \left( - \frac{a}{2}-1 \right) u(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2-2} \bigg) g(Y_t) X_t \, dt \end{align*}$$

Hence, by the definition of $f$ and $g$,

$$\begin{align*}
&\psi_1(t)+\psi_2(t)+\psi_3(t) \\ &= u(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2} g(Y_t) \cdot \left( - a \cdot (a+1) \, \frac{1}{X_t}- a \, \left( - \frac{a}{2}-1 \right) \frac{1}{X_t}- \frac{b}{2} X_t^p \right) \\ &\quad + u'(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2} g(Y_t) \cdot \left( (a+1) \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{X_t}}  + \left( - \frac{a}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{X_t}} - \frac{a}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{X_t}}) \right) \\ &\quad + u''(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-a/2} g(Y_t) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}  g(Y_t) X_t^{-a/2} \left( u''(\sqrt{X_t}) + u'(\sqrt{X_t}) X_t^{-1/2} - u(\sqrt{X_t}) \cdot \left( a^2 X_t^{-1} +b X_t^p \right) \right) \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

By assumption, $u$ satisfies

$$X_t \cdot u''(\sqrt{X_t}) + \sqrt{X_t} u'(\sqrt{X_t}) - u(\sqrt{X_t}) \cdot (a^2+b X_t^{p+1}) = 0 $$

Dividing by $X_t$ yields

$$u''(\sqrt{X_t}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{X_t}} u'(\sqrt{X_t}) - u(\sqrt{X_t}) \cdot (a^2 X_t^{-1} +b X_t^{p}) = 0 \tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find

$$\psi_1(t)+\psi_2(t)+\psi_3(t)=0.$$

This finishes the proof.